# How to limit the elements created by explode()

Tags: php, limit, explode

If i have a string like

"1234 Name Extra"

And i do

```
list($postcode, $city) = explode(" ", $string);
```

It turns out that $postcode is "1234" and $city is "Name". I would like $city to be "Name Extra"

How can i do this?

Comment: Consider using regular expression to determine what is what. http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the third parameter ($limit) of explode. The resulting array will have $limit Elements.

```
list($postcode, $city) = explode(" ", $string, 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
list($postcode, $city) = explode(" ", $string, 2);
```

Comment: Please always post some semblance of an explanation with your answers.  Code-only answers do very little to educate future readers.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [PHP docs](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), you'll see that `explode()` has an optional third parameter that specifies how many times you want to explode.

Answer (score 2):

From the manual:

```
array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )
```

so you use the optional limit argument, in your case 2, I believe