# Getting first two words from string in php

Tags: php, string

I have string like:

```
$message="AB 1234 Hello, how are you?
```

I want to get like this:

```
$message[0] = AB
$message[1] = 1234
$message[2] = Hello, how are you?
```

Please don't suggest substr function because length of first two words may vary but they will have spaces in between.
Any other suggestion?

Comment: Please check the problem and requirements again

Comment: i see no problem with my suggestion. it is  identical to the 4 purposed answers below

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/8456847/2943403

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) with a limit, eg

```
$message = explode(' ', $message, 3);
```

If you need more flexibility around the word delimiter, you can do something similar with [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

```
$message = preg_split('/[\s,]+/', $message, 3)
```

Demo - http://codepad.org/1gLJEFIa

Comment: Demo - http://codepad.org/kZc2jGW9

Answer (score 6):

you can use the following function.

```
// Example 1
$pizza  = "piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";
$pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);
echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
echo $pieces[1]; // piece2

output:
//piece1
//piece2
```

More information:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: $words  = "Hello, how are you doing?";
$allwords = explode(" ", $words);

$lenght = count($allwords);

for ($i=0; $i < $lenght; $i++) { 
 
 echo $allwords[$i]."<br>";
}

Answer (score 3):

If *words* are simply the first two chunks delimited by sequential whitespace, you could do...

```
$words = preg_split("/\s+/", $str);
```

If you want the first two, you could use `preg_split()`'s limit argument (thanks [Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil)).

Comment: [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) has a limit arg too you know ;)

Comment: @Phil I'm getting lazy... :)

Answer (score 2):

Check out [sscanf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php), be sure to read the user submitted comments though too. You can find a better description of the formats allowed at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/.

```
<?php
$string = 'AB 1234 Hello, how are you?';
$array = sscanf($string, '%s %d %[^$]');
var_dump($array);
/*
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "AB"
      [1]=>
      int(1234)
      [2]=>
      string(19) "Hello, how are you?"
    }
*/
```