# Alternative to using implode and explode

Tags: php

I want to get the first two words in the string:

`The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog`

The result should be:
`The quick brown`

The implode/explode example code is:

```
implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'), 0, 2))
```

Is there an alternative to achieve the same result without using arrays?

Comment: If you are sure of the indexes then why not use: `$arr= explode(' ', $string);` and then display it as: `$arr[0].' '.$arr[1]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting first two words from string in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263523/getting-first-two-words-from-string-in-php)

Comment: *"This is not a duplicate [...] which outputs the message as array elements"* - Then use `implode()` to combine those array elements into a `string`. So yes, this _is_ a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: So to answer the question "Is there a better alternative?" The answer is no?

Comment: Well, what do you mean by "better alternative"? Better in what way? `explode()` and `implode()` are the typical methods you'd use to do string manipulation; it breaks into into parts (as an `array`), you take the parts you want (via `array_slice`) and combine them back into a `string` (via `implode()`)

Comment: My use of "better" is not great, granted. I mean a way without using arrays.

Comment: Fair enough; better is generally not a great word to use on Stackoverflow (simply due to its ambiguity). I personally don't know of a way to do this without arrays; `explode()` returns an `Array`, using Regex to split on words and spaces would also be an `Array`, etc. So without Arrays? Not that I now of. Curious; why are you opposed to Arrays?

Comment: Not opposed, just curious as there are usually multiple different techniques to get to the same result.

Comment: Gotcha. You'd be amazed some of the "requirements" I've seen imposed by developers for various reasons  But anyway; the way PHP treats strings is as an Array of strings; `$string = 'Testing';`, followed by `$string[0]` will show `'T'`, `$string[1]` would be `'e'`, and so on. So following that logic, `explode()`, `preg_split()` and `sscanf()` (the 3 examples on the linked duplicate) all return an `Array`. So even if you wanted a non-array solution, you'd still get an Array in some capacity.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realise strings were arrays under the bonnet.
A lot learnt here including how to be clearer in question asking

Answer (score 0):

don't use implode, just use explode

```
$string="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"; 
$ex=explode(' ',$string);
echo $ex[0];  //result= The
echo $ex[1];  //result= quick
```